# How to perform foreach loop in knockout.js for a multiple row and column list

Tags: knockout.js

[image]

I have read about each function in knockout js, but i am trying to perform one where there are 3 rows, so after a row of 3 users are populated, knock out should go to the next row and populate it, how do i achieve this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group the users based on their indexes. The end goal is to create an array of arrays where the inner arrays contain the data for each column. You can create a [computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) property like this:

```
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.users = [
   { name: "name 1"}, 
   { name: "name 2"}, 
   { name: "name 3"}, 
   { name: "name 4"}, 
   { name: "name 5"}, 
   { name: "name 6"}, 
   { name: "name 7"}, 
 ];

  // this array looks: [[user1,user2,user3], [user4,user5,user6]]
  self.groupedUsers = ko.computed(function() {
    var rows = [];

    self.users.forEach(function(user, i) {
      // whenever i = 0, 3, 6 etc, we need to initialize the inner array
      if (i % 3 == 0)
        rows[i/3] = [];

      rows[Math.floor(i/3)][i % 3] = user;
    });

    return rows;
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

And in your html:

```
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: groupedUsers">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
      <td data-bind="text: name">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

`$data` here is the inner array in context. [You can read about binding context here.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

[Here's a fiddle for testing](http://jsfiddle.net/adigas/5asL91fv/)

---

CSS options:

I'm not an expert, but the key here is whether you have a `container` for each `row`. If you didn't have a separator between each row, you could achieve this using pure `css`. You could use `float: left` on the user containers and it would take the number of users per line based on the screen size and container width.

The same line of argument can be made if you're using a framework like `bootstrap` or `foundation` which have grid classes to help out. You would contain all the `column`s within a `row` class and the grid would automatically adjust based on the screen size and custom `col-md` and `col-sm` classes you set based on your device-level requirement.

Comment: i have tried to implement your answer, but then i noticed that i am arranging my profile with <ul><li></li><li></li></ul><ul><li></li><li></li></ul>

Comment: @EshiettOto-obong Create a wrapping `div` and just replace the `tr` with `ul`: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adigas/5asL91fv/1/).  If you don't want to create an additional wrapper `div`, you can use knockout's [containerless control flow syntax](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-4-using-foreach-without-a-container-element) like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adigas/5asL91fv/2/)

Comment: i have an issue i had after following your answer in this post, i posted, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387543/knockoutjs-my-computed-function-is-not-dynamically-changing-the-elements-in-my , please can you take a look at it.